# Help with this reg. exp. in PHP

Tags: php, regex

i don't know about regular expressions, I asked here for one that:
gets either anything up to the first parenthesis/colon or the first word inside the first parenthesis. This was the answer:

```
preg_match('/(?:^[^(:]+|(?<=^\\()[^\\s)]+)/', $var, $match);
```

I need an improvement, I need to get either anything up to the first parenthesis/colon/**quotation marks** or the first word inside the first parenthesis.

So if I have something like:

```
$var = 'story "The Town in Hell"s Backyard';     // I get this: $match = 'story';
$var = "screenplay (based on)";             // I get this: $match = 'screenplay';
$var = "(play)";                                  // I get this: $match = 'play';
$var = "original screen";              // I get this: $match = 'original screen';
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't know anything about regex, maybe you are better off writing a small function that does what you want with `strstr()` and `substr()` etc. The regex will only get more complex and even less maintainable than it already is for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a simple change:

`preg_match('/(?:^[^(:"]+|(?<=^\()[^\s)]+)/', $var, $match);`

I just added quotes inside the `[^...]` box, along with the colon and open parens.